# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I get the following error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Lenovo K10a40 in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
C:\Users\user\Desktop\chatflutter\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.1.1] C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\06c7fe4f2370f2607dc0a1e2da67849f\transformed\jetified-firebase-analytics-21.1.1\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.firebase.firebase_analytics" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.1.1] C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\06c7fe4f2370f2607dc0a1e2da67849f\transformed\jetified-firebase-analytics-21.1.1\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.firebase.firebase_analytics" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 31s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

How to fix the above error?

Answer (score 1):

change the minimun sdk version in `/android/app/build.gradle`

```
minSdkVersion 19
```